# Some question about Cordova build process for Android

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build, ionic4

I started learning Ionic, created an app, run it on browser and android emulator. Everything seems fine. I'm just curious about a few things but unfortunately couldn't find anything specific on them.

When I run the command `ionic cordova build android`, following lines appear on the console -

```
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[13:16:50]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.1

(--- SOME MORE LINES ---)

> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\atiyar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_202
studio

Welcome to Gradle 4.10.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:

(--- SOME MORE LINES ---)

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 20s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
.....................................................................................
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom

(--- 257 MORE DOWNLOADS --- )
(--- SOME MORE LINES ---)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 47m 52s
46 actionable tasks: 46 executed
Built the following apk(s):
        D:\Code\Ionic\IonicSideMenuApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

I wanted to know -

1. Why the project is identified as "Android Studio project"?

   - I created the project using Ionic CLI.
2. Why is it downloading gradle-4.1-all.zip?

   - As instructed [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android#gradle), I installed the latest version (5.2.1) of Gradle and added it to the PATH
3. What are all those .pom and .jar files (downloaded after gradle-4.1-all.zip) used for?

   - I never worked with Gradle build system before
   - Looks like the downloaded files get stored in C:\Users\UserName\.gradle directory
4. If these are the files used to build the app then how is the main gradle binary used with them?

   - If that is "how gradle works", could you please suggest a simplified resource to learn about it? I tried gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html).
5. How did it identify Gradle 4.10.1?

   - I found gradle-4.10.1 on my machine in the Android Studio installation directory, but it's not added to the PATH

So, it seems I'm trying to have a clear picture of "under-the-hood of Cordova build process for Android". Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cordova is, essentially, just a web page on top of a native Android project. Your cordova app runs in a native project's `WebView`. Ionic runs on top of Cordova
2. Native android projects use gradle as its build tool
3. `.pom` files are configuration files of native android third-party dependencies, e.g. `config.xml` for a cordova plugin; `.jar` is a java archive, the third-party dependency, in your case
4. I don't quite understand the question, but gradle isn't really anything you need to worry about as a Cordova developer. Android Studio runs in its own sandbox, your global gradle does not affect the sandbox. Do not upgrade the gradle of that sandbox, it might break your cordova project
5. `cordova-android` is what sets the gradle version in your native project